# Suitable `.gitignore` For Node.js

Tags: git, node.js, github, npm, gitignore

### Tree structure

That's how my Node.js project is organized:

```
/
| - node_modules               [+ INCLUDE]
|   | - my-mod1
|   |   | - node_modules       [- IGNORE]
|   |   |   | - external-mod1 
|   |   |   | - external-mod2 
|   |   | - src
|   |   |   | - node_modules   [+ INCLUDE]
|   |   |   |   | - my-mod2 
|   |   |   |   | - my-mod3
|   | - my-mod4
```

### My plan

When publishing my project to GitHub:

- I **want** to include **`my-mod`s**.
- I **don't want** to include the
  **`external-mod`s**.

That means:

- I **want** to include the top-level `/node_modules` folder.
- I **don't want** to include `node_modules` folders which are **direct childs** of a module folder.
- But I **want** to include `node_moduels` folders which are **childs of a `src`** folder.

### What I did

I added the following lines to `/.gitignore`:

```
#################  
## npm
#################

npm-debug.log
node_modules/
!/node_modules/
!src/node_modules/
```

### My question

Which **`.gitignore` rules** do I need **to include the right `node_modules`** folders (as described above)?

Thanks - if anything's unclear, please comment.

Comment: Personally, including any node_modules that could be retrieved with an npm-install is a bad smell.  There are several places on the web I've read this, here's one: http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/11/10/node-habits-2016 and it actually caused deployment issues for me once because some node_modules need to be built a certain way for different platforms

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since your structure is quite organized you could use this pattern to accomplish the task.

```
/node_modules/*/node-modules/
```

The above pattern will ignore node_modules under module folders, my-mod1,my-mod4 and others.

The above line will still allow the node_modules under src directory to be included when you push to github.

Answer (score 8):

`node_modules/**/node_modules` should work for what you are trying to do.

Tip: [GitHub provides](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/) standard `.gitignore`'s for various languages like [Node](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. - I already knew the `github/gitignore` repository, but there wasn't anything suitable for my usecase.

Comment: I thought you probably did but it's always handy to point out :-) did the `.gitignore` line work for you?

Comment: No, it's a good idea (thanks), but unfortunately didn't handle the `./node_modules` inside the `src` folders correctly. - I tried to define the condition in another way (see my own answer).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your answers.

I rethought the condition and decided to declared the condition the other way - it works perfectly:

```
node_modules/*/node_modules
```

I hope this is able to help anybody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
node_modules/*
!node_modules/**/node_modules
```

maybe?